# Are parentheses considered operators in Java?

Tags: java

I'm studying intro level Java and arithmetic expressions. The book talks about using parenthesis to override the precedence of other operators, which led me to this question:

Would parentheses used to show precedence be considered an operator, or something else entirely?

Comment: Why does this matter?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: I don't believe Java defines them as operators.  Although, if mathematics does, then I guess the reference wouldn't be incorrect.

Comment: Java does not define them as operators, but Java does follow the standard mathematical order of operations so just consider them to be grouping operators.  Or, you can call them Dhvani Operators, what they're called is less important than what they do :)

Comment: They are special characters but they are [specified as separators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12), not operators.

Comment: Why the down-votes? This is a specific clear question on a topic of importance for doing language analysis/parsing, or just getting a clearer picture of how syntax works.

Comment: @BasilBourque Lack pf prior research. The answer is right there in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12) whence I cited it, and also in the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) that markspace cited. I really expect one or other of these to have been consulted first. He didn't even name his book.

Comment: See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/208350/ ... and note how long ago the question was asked.

Comment: @Reilas In mathematics an operator is a function from one space of functions to another. Parentheses don't do that. They just clarify the notation.

Comment: @user207421, aren't they part of the _order of operations_ principle?  Or, is that specific to operations, and not operators ....

Comment: @Reilas No, they are part of operator precedence, not order of evaluation, which is left to right in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis characters are used heavily in the Java language.

- A separator character for several statements, such as *if*, *for*, *switch*, etc.
- A common delimiter for parameter and argument lists
- A grouping symbol for arithmetic expressions
- An operator for cast expressions

Although Java does not support operator overloading, the cast operator is a pair of parenthesis.

Answer (score -1):

## Separators

Per the [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76448836/are-parentheses-considered-operators-in-java#comment134799851_76448836), [parentheses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Parentheses_in_programming_languages) are defined as [separators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.11), not [operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there are a few definitions for *"operator"*.

*[Wikipedia – Operator (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics))*.
*[Wikipedia – Operator (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming))*.

In terms of syntax, within computer programming, arithmetic operations are signified by *["operators"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)*.

This is not the case with *mathematics*, which defines them as *[operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics))*.

Although, that does not discredit your question.

> *"Would parentheses used to show precedence be considered an operator, or something else entirely?"*

Now, obviously, in Java, for it to be deemed a syntax *operator*, it would require, at the least, one *[operand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand)*.
This is not what you're asking.

You're talking about an *operator* in the *mathematical* context.

So, I would say it *is* a programming operator, and *is not* a mathematical operator.

I believe most of your inquiry stems from the *[order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)* principle, which includes the parentheses as an aggregate.
Which almost credits it as being an operator.

Great question.

Comment: The question is whether parentheses are considered operators *in Java,* and it is answered by the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12). Nothing trumps that. Not even Wikipedia ;-)

Comment: @user207421, are you going to write an answer?